# What is the purpose of setting a client character set when connecting to mySQL in PHP?

Tags: mysqli

Using mysqli I might do:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

I assume that $mysqli->get_charset gets the current setting which is otherwise set by this.

This is the character set used for the client-server connection (PHP to talk to the MySQL server) - not the collation on the database I believe?

What is the significance of this? What is it used for? If there is a chunk of utf8 encoded data being passed from PHP to the MySQL Server (say in an INSERT query) what difference will this setting make? If this setting was latin1 would it matter?

Should it be the same as the collation used in the database?

Answer (score 0):

do you use notepadd++ ? if you can see the images in notepadd ++ in dependence of encode is show "í" ... mysql set_charset work at same

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP1yT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFOZg.png)